# Can you say "raise awareness about something"?

Tags: prepositions

As the title says, I was wondering whether it would be correct/okay to say "raise awareness **about** an issue". Specifically the **about** is leaving me confused.

I guess you could use **of** or **for** (can you?), but I don't like the way that sounds, compared to about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All three prepositions can be used after **raise awareness** but not necessarily in the same context.

Which you choose depends partly on preference and partly on what you want to say. **Of** and **about** are generally interchangeable (although in most cases I would opt for **of**).

Illustrative examples are:

> We need to raise (the public's) awareness of the fire danger this summer.
>
> We need to raise (the public's) awareness about the need to take fire precautions.

**For** can be used as a preposition or a conjunction meaning **because**.

> We need to raise awareness for there is much at stake.
>
> We need to raise awareness for the sake of the nation's future.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can. [It is quite common](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=%22raise%20awareness%20about%22).

Answer (score 0):

To raise awareness about _____ is correct. 'Of' might be possible, perhaps in the UK(?), but in US/Canada I'm confident everyone uses 'about'.

Answer (score 0):

Google Ngram Viewer [shows](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=raise%20awareness%20*&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t2%3B%2Craise%20awareness%20%2A%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Braise%20awareness%20of%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Braise%20awareness%20about%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Braise%20awareness%20and%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Braise%20awareness%20among%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Braise%20awareness%20in%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Braise%20awareness%20on%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Braise%20awareness%20that%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Braise%20awareness%20within%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Braise%20awareness%20amongst%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Braise%20awareness%20for%3B%2Cc0) that 'raise awareness of' is more than three times as common than 'raise awareness about'. 'Raise awareness about' is used [slightly more in AmEng](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=raise%20awareness%20*&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=17&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t2%3B%2Craise%20awareness%20%2A%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Braise%20awareness%20of%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Braise%20awareness%20about%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Braise%20awareness%20and%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Braise%20awareness%20among%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Braise%20awareness%20in%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Braise%20awareness%20that%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Braise%20awareness%20on%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Braise%20awareness%20for%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Braise%20awareness%20levels%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Braise%20awareness%20within%3B%2Cc0) and [slightly less in BrEng](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=raise%20awareness%20*&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=18&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t2%3B%2Craise%20awareness%20%2A%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Braise%20awareness%20of%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Braise%20awareness%20and%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Braise%20awareness%20about%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Braise%20awareness%20among%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Braise%20awareness%20in%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Braise%20awareness%20amongst%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Braise%20awareness%20on%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Braise%20awareness%20that%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Braise%20awareness%20within%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Braise%20awareness%20for%3B%2Cc0).